# Django - getting a list of groups of a loggedin user. No data or "Cannot resolve keyword 'group' into field. Choices are: id, name, permissions, user"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-2.0

The version of Django I am using is 2.0.7.

In my app, which is basically kind of a multiple users blog, there are users and groups, to which they belong to. There is a Many-To-Many relationship between them. Each user can sign up, later log in set up or join a group and post in his/her group.

I have a problem with restrictions in the form that the user can post only in the group to which he/she belongs to.

I think that the whole issue I have is limited to retrieving the fields from Many-To-Many relationships. I cannot obtain the list of groups to which a logged in user belongs to.

**groups/models.py**

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    description_html = models.TextField(editable=False, default='', blank=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='GroupMember')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        self.description_html = misaka.html(self.description)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('groups:single', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})

class GroupMember(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='memberships', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_group', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('group', 'user')
```

**posts/models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    message_html = models.TextField(editable=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='posts', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.message_html = misaka.html(self.message)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:single', kwargs={'username':self.user.username,
                                                'pk':self.pk})
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        unique_together = ['user', 'message']
```

**posts/views.py**

```
class CreatePost(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.CreateView):
    form_class = forms.PostForm
    model = models.Post

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({"user": self.request.user})
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**posts/forms.py**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("message", "group")
        model = models.Post

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop("user", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            self.fields["group"].queryset = (
                models.Group.objects.filter(
                    pk__in=user.groups.values_list("group__pk", flat=True)
                )
            )
```

I get an error:

"Cannot resolve keyword 'group' into field. Choices are: id, name, permissions, user"

The problem seems to be with this line from forms.py

```
pk__in=user.groups.values_list("group__pk", flat=True)
```

I changed pk to id:

```
id__in=user.groups.values_list("id", flat=True)
```

Then, I do not have any error, but in the form there are no groups to which the user belongs to (and he does belong to some groups).

I did some tests and all the groups appear, if I print:

```
models.Group.objects.all()
```

Also, if I check the number of members for each group, it is also correct.

However, empty queryset appear, if I print:

```
user.groups.all()
```

"auth.Group.None" appears, if I print:

```
qs = user.groups
print(qs)
```

The data about the user are retrieved correctly, everything is correct if I print:

```
user
```

**The question**

Do you know how I can get the data to which groups user obtained from kwargs.pop("user", None) belongs to? Why is my current solution wrong?

**Update 28.07**

So I found the solution. Thanks a lot for the help to Willem and Jerin :) Your posts were really useful.

So instead of making things complex how it was, I approached it the other way round to make it simple. I did not look for the groups in the user object as I did in the code above, but for the user in the group objects. Here is the code:

**posts/forms.py**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("message", "group")
        model = models.Post

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop("user", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            self.fields["group"].queryset = models.Group.objects.filter(members = user)
```

If you see any obvious drawbacks of this code, please let me know.

**Update 2.08**

I figured out another solution. Maybe someone will find it useful too. There is something like reverse lookup and it can be achieved by assigning as the attribute to the user object either the name of the group and suffix `_set` (in my case it would be `group_set`) or giving the `related_name` to the field of the model, which we use (in my case it would be members).

In other words `user.group_set` or `user.members` if `related_name='members'` should work too.

Comment: But your `user.groups` is already a queryset of `Group`s (and furthermore *not* the `Group` you defined I think, but the Django `Group`s.

Comment: Did you change the `User` model? Since right now the Django `User` is pointing to the Django `Group`, the defined `Group`s here are not relevant (according to Django).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Well, that makes sense. You are right, I have an app accounts whose models include `User` model, which inherits from `auth.models.User` and `auth.models.PermissionsMixin` but does not have any model field. In the admin panel I have Users (full of Users) and Groups (empty) in 'AUTHENTICATION AND AUTHORIZATION' and two separate positions for the apps: Users in Accounts (empty) and Groups in Groups (full). Exactly how you thought.

Comment: To sum up, user.groups refer to the groups in authentication and authorization, which are empty, instead of groups in the groups app. Thanks again. If I figure out the solution for this issue, I'm going to post it here.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem do you know whether there is another solution than renaming the app 'Groups'? I've tried a lot of solutions, looked for it a lot, but I cannot fix it... The thing is that there is a Many-To-Many relationship registered for user with the Groups app (it appears as 'groups_group' on the list of fields - I tried it instead of groups and it does not work), but I cannot 'enter' it in any way.